# How to extract data form the below HTML code using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data from the div with class 'cinema' and 'timings' using `BeautifulSoup` in `python3` . How can i do it using `soup.findAll` ?

```
<div data-order="0" class="cinema">
<div class="__name">SRS Shoppers Pride Mall<span class="__venue">&nbsp;-&nbsp; Bijnor</span>
</div>
<div class="timings"><span class="__time _available" onclick="fnPushWzKmEvent('SRBI',ShowData);fnCallSeatLayout('SRBI','22876','ET00015438','01:30 PM');">01:30 PM</span><span class="__time _center _available" onclick="fnPushWzKmEvent('SRBI',ShowData);fnCallSeatLayout('SRBI','22877','ET00015438','04:00 PM');">04:00 PM</span><span class="__time _right _available" onclick="fnPushWzKmEvent('SRBI',ShowData);fnCallSeatLayout('SRBI','22878','ET00015438','06:30 PM');">06:30 PM</span><span class="__time _available" onclick="fnPushWzKmEvent('SRBI',ShowData);fnCallSeatLayout('SRBI','22879','ET00015438','09:00 PM');">09:00 PM</span>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
for div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cinema'}):
    print div.text # It printed nothing ,the program just ended
```

Comment: for div in soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cinema'}):

Comment: print div.text
It printed nothing ,the program just ended

Answer (score 1):

You can specify both classes in `findAll`:

```
soup.findAll(True, {'class': ['cinema', 'timings']})
```

Answer (score 0):

The "div" you are interested in is another "div" child. To get that "div" you can use the [`.select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = <your html>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for div in soup.select('div.cinema > div.timings'):
    print(div.get_text(strip=True))
```

Or iterate the `find_all()` result and use the `.find()` method to return those "div" where `class: "timings"`

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='cinema'):
    timings = div.find('div', class_='timings')
    print(timings.get_text(strip=True))
```